# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement github-repo==2019.2.23 (from -r /tmp/build_ae8c4ea0_/requirements.txt () (from versions: none)

Tags: python, git, web, heroku, pycharm

I'm trying to deploy my web server on heroku, but i'm getting this error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement github-repo==2019.2.23 (from -r /tmp/build_ae8c4ea0_/requirements.txt (line 10)) (from versions: none)

when i checked the libraries i have - i got this on git bash:

$ pip install github-repo

Requirement already satisfied: github-repo in c:\users\ruba\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (2019.2.23)
Requirement already satisfied: values in c:\users\ruba\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from github-repo) (0.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: runcmd in c:\users\ruba\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from github-repo) (0.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Click in c:\users\ruba\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from github-repo) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: public in c:\users\ruba\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from github-repo) (0.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\ruba\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from github-repo) (41.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\ruba\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from github-repo) (2.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in c:\users\ruba\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from runcmd->github-repo) (5.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\ruba\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests->github-repo) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\ruba\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests->github-repo) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\ruba\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests->github-repo) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\ruba\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests->github-repo) (1.25.11)

removed all the requirements with version 0.0.0 but that wasn't the problem

also i tried to install github-repo from pycharm terminal but got the same error
pip install github-repo
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement github-repo (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for github-repo
:(

here is the requirement.txt file that i got

```
aiohttp==3.7.2
async-timeout==3.0.1
aiohttp==3.7.2
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==20.2.0
cached-property==1.5.2
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
dulwich==0.20.11
Flask==1.1.2
github-repo==2019.2.23
github-webhook==1.0.4
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
multidict==5.0.0
psutil==5.7.3
pyee==7.0.4
python-dotenv==0.15.0
python-git-secrets==0.1.3
requests==2.24.0
six==1.15.0
slackclient==2.9.3
slackeventsapi==2.2.1
standardjson==0.3.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.25.11
webhooks==0.4.2
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wrapt==1.12.1
yarl==1.6.2
```

Comment: I found 2 links for `github-repo` at https://libraries.io/pypi/github-repo. Both links returned error 404. It seems the repository and the package existed but were removed and no longer available. You need to find a replacement.

Comment: i couln't find a replacment :( that so weird, i've got another project that uses the same requirements (two weeks ago!), but works perfectly till now, may that be caused by the interpreter?i created a virtualenv in a file by python -m venv venv/ using git bash, then activate it ,then when i opened a python file - there was no interpreter in the file -so i used the base iterpreter